# What is the best way to suspend a file upload using the filepicker.io JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

I am using the [store](https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#store) function from filepicker's JavaScript API to upload files to Amazon S3, like so:

```
filepicker.store(input, @onUploadSuccess, @onUploadError, @onUploadProgress)
```

The files are fairly big (several megabytes). Therefore, the users should have the option to suspend the upload after it has been started.

Here's the question:

*How would you go about stopping the upload?*

Looking at the API documentation, the only thing I can think of is finishing the upload and deleting the file from the server afterwards. That feels wrong, though.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way of suspending or canceling an upload once it's in progress.